# Is it advisable to use global variable in smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, deferred-transactions

I know we can use global variable in our smart contract. So, How can I make sure that nobody can access my global variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Global variables are more or less a design thing. **I personally do not like them because of object-orientation for languages like c++.** They are good for script languages, but if your application or contract gets complex, things get complicated and they are hard to maintain.

However you **do not have to worry about access** of our global variable because of the application isolation of the WebAssembly virtual machine. Also they only are accessibly during your action excecution. Your **contract code/variables/members will be reinitiated on every action call.** If you want to persist your variables you have to use the [multi_index (aka Persistence API)](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/db-api).

It may be possible to store abitrary members/attributes of your contracts in the table if you select a fitting table schema. Maybe something like this:

```
ID (unint64_T) | Attribut (String) | Value (String)
0              | 'mCounter'        | '5' 
1              | 'mComplexAttribut'| '{ key: 1, key2: {...}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Global variables should be used sparingly in C++ programs and only used when absolutely necessary. It's good practice to keep variables limited in scope (using keywords `static`, `private`, etc) to protect unintentional modification of their value. You can create functions to allow modification of these private members from other parts of your program.